# a little modification needed in $('#id').attr(); query

Tags: jquery

```
         <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="btn btn-xs bg-primary">
                  <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0"  data-toggle="friendRequest"  data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" title="Friend Request" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" id="friendRequestPopover"></i>
               </a>
               <span class="counter" id="requests"></span>
        </li>
       <!--in above code i have to show popover like fb popovers-->
        data=0;
        $.ajax({
            url:"selectRequests.php",
            type:"post",
            data:data,
            success : function(response){
                    var data=JSON.parse(response);
                    if (data==0) {
                        $('#requests').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('#requests').append(Object.keys(data).length);
                        $( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", "awais");
                        $( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", "ahmad");
                    }
                },error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //$("#requests").html(errorThrown + textStatus);
                }
            });
```

When i am adding $( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", "ahmad"); it replace data-content with "ahmad". How can i concatenate "awais" and "ahmad"?
When i `json` will respond i will add friend request 1 by 1 in data-content.That's why i m trying  to add two `attr();`.

Comment: Without changing the above code? You can't. Right now line 2 is just overwriting line 1, and if you can't change the code I'm not sure what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: If you can't change the code what were you thinking you could do in the first place? Problem is not clear ... you need to add more details about this situation

Comment: so what should be changed in the code to achieve this?

Comment: why can't you combine them into one line and concatenate the two strings yourself?

Comment: ok let me edit my question

Comment: Suggest you take the time to read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and then start making questions that are complete and don't leave people guessing about the use case or higher level problems you might have

Comment: If you want multiple values why not make it an array? What do you use it for? Also not clear why these would be hard coded values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is data-attribute, you can get the content of data-attribute using 
$("#friendRequestPopover").data("content") this gives you the current data 
and append with ahmad using '+' and set it back using $("#friendRequestPopover").data("content",newContent)

check this snippet

```js
var existingRequest = $("#friendRequestPopover").data("content");
var content = existingRequest + "ahmad"
$("#friendRequestPopover").data("content", content);
console.log($("#friendRequestPopover").data("content"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-content="awaiz" id="friendRequestPopover">
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.attr()` method doesn't have an option to automatically combine values given to it. You'll have to provide your own code/instructions for the concatenation.

1) If you know both of the values you want to combine at the same time, you should be able to concatenate them before setting the attribute:

```
$( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", "awais" + "ahmad");
```

2) If they're actually being set in separate locations in your code, for at least one of them, you'll want to determine the current value before adding to it. To help with that, you can use the `.attr()` method's [option for providing an iterator function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), which will receive the current value as an argument.

```
$( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", "awais");

$( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content", function (i, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + "ahmad";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few options you could do.

**Using different data attributes:**

```
$("#friendRequestPopover").attr("data-firstname", "awais");
$("#friendRequestPopover").attr("data-lastname", "ahmad");

console.log( $("#friendRequestPopover").data('firstname') + ' ' + $("#friendRequestPopover").data('lastname') ); // awais ahmad
```

**Concatenating existing attribute:**

```
$("#friendRequestPopover").attr("data-content", "awais");
$("#friendRequestPopover").attr("data-content", $(this).data('content') + " ahmad");

console.log( $("#friendRequestPopover").data('content') ); // awais ahmad
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var data=$("#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content")
data=data+"ahmad"

$( "#friendRequestPopover" ).attr("data-content",data)
```

This should do it!!